# Terminate infinite loop after 20 seconds in android

Tags: java, android, time, timer

I have one infinite for loop and i want to run this for loop for 20 seconds after that i want to terminate the loop so what can i do for this?

Here is my code in android:

```
do {
    rl += Character.toString((char) in.read());
    // Log.i("RL", "" + rl);
    if (rl.contains("<") && checkStream(rl)) {
        // Log.i("RL INSIDE", "" + rl);
        getNumerAndStatusFromRLString(rl);
        rl = "";
    }
    if (20 SECONDS COMPLETED) {
        Log.i("<rl>", "exit");
        break;
    }
} while (true);
```

So what can i do to check that 20 seconds is compeleted and now its time to terminate.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of the options may be get time before the loop and while looping check 20 seconds elapsed or not.

Something like below: Not sure about the efficiency.

```
   long startTime=   System.currentTimeMillis();
do {

......

     long currTime=  System.currentTimeMillis();
     long elapsedtime = currTime - startTime;
     if(elapsedtime > 20000)
      {
      break;
      }
}
```

Comment: yes i have same idea but how can i get the difference of 20 seconds?

Comment: elapsed time should be compared with 20*1000. It's in milliseconds.

Comment: @ Graham : yes but it is taking more than 2 minutes to terminate in case of "20*1000"

Comment: I'd also add a sleep of 1-10 millisecs into the loop to prevent pegging the cpu.

Comment: @Nick: Isn't sleep stops your thread? Doesn't that mean looping won't continue?

Comment: @RushabhPatel: You can't exactly catch 20 SECONDS, that's why > symbol is for. Because of processing time we don't on which second next iteration executes.

Comment: @thinksteep: a 1 millisecond sleep time will make the loop pause for 1/1000th of a second.  You won't be able to notice it but to a CPU a millisecond may as well be a year. Such a change can reduce 100% cpu usage to virtually 0% cpu usage.

Comment: Also, you should never do something like this from the main thread.  You should spawn a second thread to run this kind of a job.  Otherwise your UI can (and typically will) become unresponsive.

Comment: @Nick: I agree with your above statement, but still I didn't get how pause may help where OP wants to loop and stop after certain seconds. As well as if you could elaborate on "Such a change can reduce 100% cpu usage to virtually 0% cpu usage" that would help me learning something.

Comment: @thinksteep - I didnt notice the in.read() call at first glance.  If this is a blocking method, ie. it only returns when characters become available to read then the sleep method is unnecessary.  Of course in this case you then have a thread that may never terminate.  So assuming all other things being equal and that you have a loop that calls no blocking methods, you have a thread that runs as fast as the cpu will let it without ever stopping.  (CONTINUED)

Comment: (...CONTINUED) If all the loop is doing is checking a boolean to see whether there is work to do, its kind of a waste unless you absolutely need the most responsive loop you can possibly get.  (In which case you should be doing something with interrupts instead, and probably not using java in the first place)  If on the other hand you can live with a ~1000hz loop frequency then you want to add a 1 ms sleep into the loop.  This allows the thread to stop for a moment and allow the cpu to do other stuff.  (CONTINUED)

Comment: yes i got your point and my issue was same as you told above. **in.read()** method is blocking the loop so i can not get the 20000 miliseconds ever and loop blocks.

Comment: (...CONTINUED) If you consider that the actual looping action takes somewhere between a nanosecond and a microsecond to complete, that 1 millisecond sleep equates to liberating 99.9% (or more) of your cpu time to do other stuff while your main loop waits for real work to do, again still maintaining that ~1000hz frequency.

Comment: @NicK: Thanks for your time on explaining. I see what you mean. Now it make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Timer Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) which you can specify the length of time for a task to run.

**One caveat emptor**: this set of functions used requires a recurring frequency but as its a one shot timing thing, you can get around it by using a handler in which you can signal to cancel!

An example would be something like this:

```
private Timer myTimer = new Timer();
private final int CANCEL_EXECUTION = 0x100;
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();

public void runFor20Sec(){
   myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
       @Override
       public void run(){
          // Do something here
          myHandler.obtainMessage(CANCEL_EXECUTION).sendToTarget();
       }
    }, System.currentTimeMillis(), 2000);
}
public class myHandler extends Handler{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        switch(msg.what){
           case CANCEL_EXECUTION :
               myTimer.cancel();
               break;
        }
    }
}
```